# Pegar a ultima posição de explode

Tags: php

Galera preciso pegar a ultima posição depois de dar um `explode`. Como faço?

```
 $geturl = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

 self::$modulo = isset($geturl[2]) ? $geturl[2] : '';
 self::$funcao = isset($geturl[3]) ? $geturl[3] : '';
 self::$chave = isset($geturl[4]) ? $geturl[4] : '';
```

Obs.: Pode acontecer de `$chave` ser nulo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a função `end()` para deixar o ponteiro do array na última posição e obter seu valor.

```
$ultimo = end($geturl);
```